# Redirect page for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following custom post type

```
        register_post_type('cp_clients', array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Clients'),
                'singular_name' => __('Client')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor')
                )
        );
```

I want to output custom content when the user calls http://blogurl.com/companies. It's a plug-in and not a theme.

Any ideas how I can redirect to a custom page/output for this URL?

Comment: You're not that cleat about what you're looking to do.  Please revise your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a redirect. You are missing the rewrite rule for your custom post type.

```
register_post_type('cp_clients', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Clients'),
        'singular_name' => __('Client')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor')
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'companies')
);
```

You should now be able to create and use single-cp_clients.php, and archive-cp_clients.php template files.  And your urls will look like example.com/comapnies and example.com/comapnies/acmecorp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

I've used this [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) successfully before, but it looks like it's been updated fairly substantially since.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I found a solution to the problem. The solution is to use "template_redirect" and to detect if the page is the post type archive page

```
 if ($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'cp_companies' && $wp_query->query_vars['name'] === '') {

}
```